# month and day only of date will be display

Tags: vb.net

I want to display the value of a date to a crystal report that was passed in a parameter.But all i want is the Month and day only consider like this format: (October 27). The code in passing the value to a parameter is OK but the result that will be display in crystal report is the problem. i already searched in google but it still no solution.

i already tried this code but its still not working

```
arrReportParameter.Add(New BPSArrays("DateFrom",dtStart.Value.ToString("MMM-dd")))
```

dtStart is the name of my DATETIMEPICKER. all are functioned well except the result for the date.

any suggestion please?

Comment: `dtStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom` `dtStart.CustomFormat = "dd/MM"` This any help?

Comment: Think you have to put this code in the form load

Comment: I already tried it. but it's still not working. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can set the format of the date-field inside the report. Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `dtStart.Value.ToString("m")` - this will give you a Month Day format.

Read through [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) Microsoft documentation, it will give you some more examples of formats.

Answer (score 0):

i already fix it just by changing the format in crystal report. thanks for the reply